# Ionic Three Tier Nesting

Tags: ionic-framework

I have the following state config for Ionic:

```
  .state('index', {
    url: '',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/home/home.html',
    controller: 'HomeCtr'
  })

  .state('index.list-folders', {
    url: '/list-folders',
    views: {
      'folderList@index': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/home/home_content.html',
        controller: 'HomeListsCtr'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('index.list-folders.list', {
    url: "/list-folders/list",
    views:{
      "listContainer@index": {
        templateUrl: "templates/home/list.html"
      }
    }
  })
```

My index state (home.html) contains the following ion-nav-view:

```
<ion-nav-view name="folderList"></ion-nav-view>
<ion-nav-view name="listContainer"></ion-nav-view>
```

I learnt from [this link](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#view-names---relative-vs-absolute-names) that by having an `@` in front of the `ion-nav-view` means that it absolutely targets the `ion-nav-view` in the parent.

However, when I try to navigate to `/list-folders/list` I get redirected back to my default stage in `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise();`